# Get the most popular jsonb value

Tags: postgresql

I have such a table:

```
                          Table "public.doc"
     Column      |           Type           |         Modifiers         
-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------
 doc             | character varying        | not null
 tags            | jsonb                    | 
 status          | character varying        |
```

The **tags** field contains multiple elements in the format:

```
["wordpre", "advantages", "skills"]
```

How do I build a query to get the most popular tags (single values)?
Request type:

```
SELECT tags, COUNT(*) AS counted
FROM doc
WHERE tags IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY tags
ORDER BY counted DESC, tags
LIMIT 10;
```

returns all string tags.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you store the tags in JSON[B], to start with?  If the key is always "tags", you are just wasting space.  As it sounds, a plain `text[]` array would be better.  If you have a fixed set of tags, even normalizing into a separate table could make sense, and then counting everything is just easy.

Answer (score 0):

**(Edited to be consistent with new version of question)**

You cannot `SELECT tags FROM doc` if you want to `GROUP BY` single elements of the lists which make up the `tags` field. You have to disaggregate those lists in a subselect:

```
SELECT tags, COUNT(*) AS counted
FROM (SELECT JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT(tags) AS tags 
        FROM doc) AS items
GROUP BY tags
ORDER BY counted DESC, tags
LIMIT 10;
```

- The function `JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT` will ignore records where `tags IS NULL`, so you don’t need further `WHERE` clauses.
- Of course, as @dezso pointed out in his comments, it is completely inefficient to use a jsonb column only to store a list of tags, and then rebuild a many-to-many table on the fly every time. You should have built that table in the first place.
- If, as I suppose, your data come in in json format, a better policy would be to process them as they arrive, by a trigger which calls `JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT` on the input. However, you said nothing of your usage of those data, so it is hard to tell how to improve efficiency.
- You ought to have very good reasons for not using a persistent many-to-many table. If you really have them, another alternative would be a column of type `text[]` instead of `jsonb`. This would enforce the way you want to use that column and be less error-prone. In that case, you’d have to use `UNNEST(tags)` instead of `JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT(tags)`.

Comment: This option I already tried before. I get an error: ERROR:  cannot extract elements from a scalar

Comment: I think you're right, it's better to switch to the many-to-many option.

Comment: The error about impossible extraction of elements from a scalar means that you are making mistakes either in the table definition or in the insert queries. Please have a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post your `CREATE TABLE doc` and some `INSERT INTO doc` queries. It is impossible to help you otherwise. As for switching to a cleaner SQL structure, in most cases it is much better.